# How can I rewrite URL which can help for SEO with multiwebsite?

Tags: multistore, url-rewrite, seo, multi-website

**I want to solve duplicate product content issue with multi website with same SKU.**

I have magento with multi website under one magento instance. Where there are two type of admin user. One is main super admin user and others are website level admin user.

There are website level catalog access for each website admin user. WEbsite admin can create their own products or they can edit products provided/shared by super admin.

Some of the products are shared between the multiple websites.

Note. Allow Store code in URL is enabled from admin for each website.

There are two website.

Example.

**Default website :- www.example.com/default**

**default is a store code for Default website.**

**Alabama website:- www.example.com/alabama**

**alabama is a store code for Alabama city website.**

**Question 1.** For Default website, I want to remove store code permanently ?

For example, hoodie product has been created by super admin and shared with two websites and shirt product created by Franchise admin under their own website.

**Question 2.** For Alabama website, I also want to remove store code from the website for those products which are shared and not edited(there is no any change in name, description, meta information etc. upto that) by Franchise admin from admin.

So for example if hoodie is shared between these two website and it is not edited by any of the website admin, product URL will be www.example.com/apparel/hoodie.html. But if Alabama website admin has changed anything(name, description, meta information etc) for 'hoodie', URL should be www.example.com/alabama/apparel/hoodie.html.

But in case if Alabama website admin has created their own product called 'shirt', URL for that product for alabama website should be www.example.com/alabama/apparel/shirt.html

Can anyone have any idea about that how this can be achieve in magento with multiwebsite?

Please let me know if require more detail. 
It is very much important for me to resolve this issue.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might not directly provide an answer however when you're doing any redirects always use a 301 as this is the best from an SEO standpoint.

I would advise doing this on an Nginx or apache level in a separate vhost. You can keep it in the same .conf file but make sure it's a different server block or else you won't be able to set it to go different places for each domain